# How to populate empty columns in all rows with a value from another row

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
num | id | value1 | value2 | ..... | valueN
____|____|________|________|_______|_______
 1  |  1 |  val1  | val2   | ..... | valN
 2  |  1 |  blah  | NULL   | ..... | NULL
 1  |  2 | val12  | val22  | ..... | valN2
 2  |  2 | blah2  | NULL   | ..... | NULL
```

`num` and `id` are a primary key. Each row that has 1 `num` is the row that has all the columns filled, all other rows for that `id` (where `num` is higher than 1) have empty columns which I want to fill with corresponding values from columns in the `num`=1 with the same `id`.

I could write a script that runs on all `num` >1 rows and and then runs on *every* empty column and brings it from the `num`=1 row, but is there a more SQLy way to do it? Something more general, without iterating every column?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to update all rows using [cross-table UPDATE JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/)

```
UPDATE mytbl AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE num = 1) AS b ON a.id = b.id
SET a.value1 = b.value1,
  a.value2 = b.value2,
...
  a.valueN = b.valueN
WHERE  a.num > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To just update the values (and preserve them if already present) the basic query would look like this:

```
update Table1 t
join (select * from Table1 where num = 1) ones
on t.id = ones.id and t.num != ones.num
set 
    t.value1 = IFNULL(t.value1, ones.value1),
    t.value2 = IFNULL(t.value2, ones.value2),
    t.valueN = IFNULL(t.valueN, ones.valueN);
```

Since it's not possible to do `update tablea from tableb set a.* = b.*` you will have to include all columns that you want to update in the query, and if I understand your question this is the exact situation you want to avoid.

Using dynamic sql and querying the information schema of the database it's possible to build an update statement that will update all columns (except the ones manually excluded). This method is a bit hackish but should work, however it might not perform well and it might be unsafe.

Given a test table named `Table1` set up as your example you can run the following code to update all columns except `id` and `num`:

```
-- base update statement
SET @sql:= 'update Table1 t
join (select * from Table1 where num = 1) ones
on t.id = ones.id and t.num != ones.num 
set ';

-- concatenate the base update with the column specific part
SELECT @stmnt := concat(@sql, group_concat(
  't.',
  COLUMN_NAME, 
  ' = IFNULL(t.',
  COLUMN_NAME,'
  , ones.',
  COLUMN_NAME,
  ')'))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'Table1'
-- exclude these columns from the update
AND column_name != 'id'
AND column_name != 'num';

-- build a statement and execute it
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @stmnt;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```